# How to trigger release in second release definition when a stage passes in first release definition in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

I have two release definitions **release-def-1** and **release-def-2** in azure devops.
I want to trigger a release in second one(release-def-2) once the deployment in first(release-def-1) succeeds.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried to find several trigger settings in release definition triggers but could not find anything relevant to what I need.

I know I can add multiple stages in the same release definition but that not what I am looking for.

Comment: Not get your latest information, if the following answer is helpful, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could not configure it in the [release trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops).

As a workaround, we could open **release-def-1** add task power shell at the end of the job and call the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to trigger release pipeline(**release-def-2**).

Power shell script:

```
$token = "{PAT}"   
$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/Release/releases?api-version=5.0"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))


$JSON = @"
{
  "definitionId": {release-def-2 definition ID}
}
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -body $JSON

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can add a [Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline) task at the end of the job and set the task running conditions: `Only when all previous tasks have succeeded`. In this way, when the first release pipeline is successfully deployed, the second release pipeline will be automatically triggered.

[image][image]